# Are there problems using PHP sessions in a server cluster?

Tags: php, cluster-computing

We are developing a web site in PHP, and we have to use sessions. The site will be published in a server cluster. How can we make that work?

Thanks.

Comment: For a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994935/php-sessions-in-a-load-balancing-cluster-how gives a lot of detailed responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you need to store your sessions in a central location like a database though. This is pretty simple and just requires you to make some changes to [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) - there's a good example of the process you need to follow [here](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

I would use memcache to store your sessions. It will be much faster than storing them in a database or disk.

Database storage is good but you will need more databases when your site becomes very high traffic. Sessions on disk will also cause a lot of IO issues when your site gets a lot of traffic. Memcache on the other hand scales much better than a DB and files.

I personally use memecache and the sites i work on get millions of hits a day. I have never had any issues with storing sessions in memcache.

Answer (score 0):

A shared NFS mount for the session directory would be an option, though I've always found nfs performance a bit slow. Alternatives are to write your own session handler using memcache or database for the sessions.

An alternative option is to load balance your web servers using [sticky sessions](http://www.markround.com/archives/33-Apache-mod_proxy-balancing-with-PHP-sticky-sessions.html), which will ensure that requests from the same client always go to the same server during the course of the session.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got multiple PHP boxes, you'll want a central session store.

Your best choices are probably database (that link from seengee's answer is a good explanation) or a dedicated [memcache](http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/) box.